# Bootstrap accordion - use <span> instead of <div> to reveal more body copy

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion, inline, html, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to use the Boostrap according to reveal more body copy - so need the revealed content to be inline with the introduction text. I'm using a more link as the trigger at the end like this:

```
<p>
 Intro text <span id="intro" class="collapse"> the rest of the sentence.</span>
 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#intro"> More</a>
</p>
```

This works when using a div but using any inline elements results in the accordion not working - even if I use a div and set it to display inline or inline-block.

Does anyone know how to make this work on inline elements? Or is there a different jquery plugin or some simple jquery that would acheive the same thing - there will be multiple accordians on the same page.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily override Bootstrap's default collapse styling by adding styles with more specificity. Just make sure to override all styles set by them properly - by default, collapsing is done by animating the `height` attribute, so you would have to make sure to include `height: auto` in all three collapse states if you do not want the height animation to kick in.

For example, you can collapse inline `span` elements by fading them out like so:

```
span.collapse {
    display: inline;
    position: static;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s ease;
       -moz-transition: opacity 0.35s ease;
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.35s ease;
         -o-transition: opacity 0.35s ease;
            transition: opacity 0.35s ease;
}
span.collapsing {
    display: inline;
    position: static;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .35s ease;
         -o-transition: opacity .35s ease;
            transition: opacity .35s ease;
}
span.collapse.in {
    display: inline;
    position: static;
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```

(they will still take up space in the flow when collapsed using this approach, so depending on your layout needs you would have to set `display:none` for the collapsed state or set `display:inline-block` for all states to be able to animate the elements' `width` etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Using Bootstrap's `collapse` plugin won't work with inline elements like `<span>`s due to how the plugin's functionality is implemented.

If you look at the Bootstrap CSS, you'll see the rule:

```
.collapse {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.35s ease;
       -moz-transition: height 0.35s ease;
        -ms-transition: height 0.35s ease;
         -o-transition: height 0.35s ease;
            transition: height 0.35s ease;
}

.collapse.in {
    height: auto;
}
```

So, `.collapse` elements are effectively hidden by making their `height` zero and setting `overflow:hidden`.

However, inline elements (like your `span`), do not accept styles like heights or vertical padding. Therefore, your span will always be visible, even with the `.collapse` class added. This also explains why the plugin stops working when you set `display:inline` on your `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

After using the right search terms, I found and impliented the following: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-shortened-text-show-more-link-jquery/